# What is a project SDK in android studio flutter project?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

When a new flutter project was created in android studio then there is No SDK in `Project Settings->Project->Project SDK` by default.
What should I use as `Project SDK` for flutter project and why it isn't defined by default?

[image]

Comment: [Flutter SDK releases](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases)?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to open project->setting->Flutter->  and you can see SDK and also change it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7pAI.png)

Comment: Filled this option do not resolve SDK missed into project structure in Android Studio